# Converting SQL To WQL

Tags: sql, wmi, sccm, wql

I created this query in SQL.  It works fine.  I confirmed the data I was getting was both accurate and what I wanted.

```
SELECT 
   v_R_System.Name0,
   v_MeteredUser.UserName,
   v_R_User.Full_User_Name0,
   User_Principal_Name0,
   physicalDeliveryOfficeNam0,
   v_GS_SoftwareFile.FileName,
   v_GS_SoftwareFile.FileVersion,
   MAX(v_MonthlyUsageSummary.LastUsage) as "LastUsedDate",
   GETDATE() as "CurrentDate",
   DATEDIFF(day,MAX(v_MonthlyUsageSummary.LastUsage),GETDATE())
FROM v_MeteredUser 
          INNER JOIN v_MonthlyUsageSummary ON v_MeteredUser.MeteredUserID = v_MonthlyUsageSummary.MeteredUserID
          INNER JOIN v_GS_SoftwareFile ON v_MonthlyUsageSummary.FileID = v_GS_SoftwareFile.FileID
          INNER JOIN v_R_System ON v_MeteredUser.UserName = v_R_System.User_Name0
          INNER JOIN v_R_User ON v_MeteredUser.UserName= v_R_User.User_Name0
WHERE v_GS_SoftwareFile.FileName in ('extra.exe')
GROUP BY v_R_System.name0,
         v_MeteredUser.UserName,
         v_R_User.Full_User_Name0,
         User_Principal_Name0,
         physicalDeliveryOfficeNam0,
         v_GS_SoftwareFile.FileName,
         v_GS_SoftwareFile.FileVersion
HAVING (DATEDIFF(day, MAX(v_MonthlyUsageSummary.LastUsage), GETDATE()) >90)
ORDER BY v_R_System.Name0,
         v_MeteredUser.UserName,
         v_R_User.Full_User_Name0,
         User_Principal_Name0,
         physicalDeliveryOfficeNam0
```

I wanted to eventually translate this over so I could use it in SCCM to populate a collection with whatever software I wanted to do a 90 day removal on.  I started converting everything over line by line, confirming the names, and that the same items existed in SCCM.  Then I started to remove lines I was pretty sure I didn’t need (there are a few more I think I can remove).  After some trial and error I came to this.

```
SELECT
      SMS_R_System.Name,
      SMS_MeteredUser.UserName,
      SMS_R_User.FullUserName,
      SMS_R_User.UserPrincipalName,
      SMS_R_User.physicalDeliveryOfficeName,
      SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName,
      SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileVersion
FROM SMS_MeteredUser
             INNER JOIN SMS_MonthlyUsageSummary ON SMS_MeteredUser.MeteredUserID = SMS_MonthlyUsageSummary.MeteredUserID
             INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile ON SMS_MonthlyUsageSummary.FileID = SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileID
             INNER JOIN SMS_R_System ON SMS_MeteredUser.UserName = SMS_R_System.Name
             INNER JOIN SMS_R_User ON SMS_MeteredUser.UserName = SMS_R_User.UserName
WHERE
     SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName in ('extra.exe') AND
     (DATEDIFF(day, SMS_MonthlyUsageSummary.LastUsage, GETDATE()) >90)
ORDER BY SMS_R_System.Name
```

The collection wasn't populating so I opened the query to try something and got an error, which would explain why it wasn't populating.  The error I am getting is:

> The specified resource class does not match the current collection type.

I am not 100% sure what I am doing wrong.  I have a similar query that works fine.

Comment: If you have a similar query that works fine, the best thing to do is convert the working query one-by-one to your new query until you find the issue

Comment: I do not.  I converted this query line by line and above is where I currently am after doing that.

Comment: Your last sentence is _I have a similar query that works fine._ that's why I suggested it. Anyway, if I was in this situation (where I don't know anything about the plarform), I would remove tables pieces until the error goes away and that give's me an idea of where the error is. Doing some reading, it seems that a "class" is just a table. BTW I know very little about SCCM, I'm throwing some suggestions out here.

Comment: I meant the other query is similar in structure (below).  It's already in WQL.  I already converted by SQL query line by line (the first code snippet above) and that conversion is in the second code snippet above.

I don't get any errors when I edit the query statement after putting it in like I do with the query in my original post.

Comment: SELECT
SMS_R_System.ResourceID,
SMS_R_System.ResourceType,
SMS_R_System.Name,
SMS_R_System.SMSUniqueIdentifier,
SMS_R_System.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,
SMS_R_System.Client
FROM
SMS_R_System
WHERE
(DateDiff(day, CreationDate, GetDate()) < 1)

Comment: So without debugging it in detail one mistake you made is in the SMS_MeteredUser.UserName = SMS_R_System.Name join. You are joining a user and a computer class on the name value which makes no sense. In the SQL you used User_name0 which I think is weirdly called LastLogonUserName in the wmi class. In general I would think the error might be related to your joining of user resources with  computer resources. You do not specify a resourceid so I think sccm would take the base class which is metered user and start with this type of resource and cannot build a system collection with it.

Comment: Yeah, I've been continuing to troubleshoot.  For that one line there was a value in SQL but no corresponding value in WQL.  I had two options and created two different queries to test; one of those was LastLogonUserName.  I have switched to that one.  It still doesn't work but it looks like I need to rework things a bit.  I was hoping to simply covert my SQL query straight to WQL, then take out the lines I don't need but that doesn't seem like it's going to happen.

Comment: Yeah I know the LastLogonUserName is not the problem but sitll wanted to mention it so you don't get problems later. I am very bad with WQL but from what I understand it is far weaker than SQL in terms of possible joins and stuff (has e.g. lazy properties that can not be joined on at all) so no in general 1:1 will not work. Unfortunately it is also very slow, I tried to figure out how to write your query in my environment but each subquery already took minutes so it was impossible to debug for me sadly. I still think if you want computers as a result you should start with sms_r_system though.

Comment: So I think I got it to work in my system (foolishly assumed that sms_r_user would be populated if sms_metered user was but this are distinct inventories and we do not ad sync users), but trying to write an answer I realised I assumed stuff (also in my comments so far) without asking you to clarify the most important thing: Are you trying to populate a user collection or a device collection?

Comment: I'm trying to populate a device collection.

Comment: I have learned that it's a lot more difficult than just editing names line by line.  I really should have used my SQL query more as a guide than anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors here that come into play (like that WQL only supports a subset of the features of SQL, or that not all names or even columns translate directly) but I think the most important thing here is that a query based collection can not operate on any query result.

The advantage of this seems to be that you don't even have to take care that your result is identifiable as a list of devices. You could select only one ambigous column from v_r_system and it would still work (in fact after saving you would notice that the query was modified automatically to include e.g. the ResourceID). It also is no problem for SCCM to populate the collection if the result has multiple columns for one record.

The downside is that you cannot just "guarantee" by your own design that what you produce is a valid list. In order for it to populate a collection you have to follow some guidelines. Now I am not really sure what is possible or whether there are exception but from what I found out by trial, the best idea is to always start with **SMS_R_SYSTEM** as your base class for device collections (and SMS_R_USER for user collections). If you join the rest to that class SCCM will always be able to populate your collection.

So with that in mind I would just rearrange the selection which should not be problematic with the inner joins (I hope my limited knowledge of SQL is not betraying me here) so it would become:

```
SELECT
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,
    SMS_MeteredUser.UserName,
    SMS_R_User.FullUserName,
    SMS_R_User.UserPrincipalName,
    SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName,
    SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileVersion
FROM SMS_R_System       
    INNER JOIN SMS_MeteredUser ON SMS_MeteredUser.UserName = SMS_R_System.LastLogonUserName
    INNER JOIN SMS_MonthlyUsageSummary ON SMS_MeteredUser.MeteredUserID = SMS_MonthlyUsageSummary.MeteredUserID
    INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile ON SMS_MonthlyUsageSummary.FileID = SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileID
    INNER JOIN SMS_R_User ON SMS_MeteredUser.UserName = SMS_R_User.UserName
WHERE       
    SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName in ('extra.exe') AND
    (DATEDIFF(day, SMS_MonthlyUsageSummary.LastUsage, GETDATE()) >90)
```

which worked fine as a query to populate my collection.
Notice I had to remove 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' because it is not present on my system, but you could in fact remove any of the properties because the query does not care for them anyway (and this sort of query will also only ever work in the "direct query edit" and never in the query designer anyway.

In general I would say while you correctly noticed that a direct translation from SQL to WQL is not possible I would still say it is a good starting point as long as you keep in mind the possible downfalls because one huge upside is just the speed. I tried some debugging via WQL on your example and in my environment most of the classes cannot even be queried without qualifying some parameter because it would take several minutes and just time out. In SQL the most it took was 15 seconds and that makes checking of your output just so much more convenient.

Comment: Very much appreciated.  I'll give that a go.  Haven't had much time to play around with my query lately.

Comment: The query runs but the results are substantially different.  In SQL Server it's about 1,000 machines.  In SCCM running in WQL it's about 9,000 machines.  That's the next thing I need to look into.

Comment: Oh I hope I did not introduce an error by changing the joins! I think you should be able to recreate the sql in the same way and work from there and compare then and as long as you keep starting with sms_r_system everything should still run

Comment: I have to look it all over on Monday.  SQL returns roughly 900 results (which is correct) and WQL was returning roughly 9,600 results.  It ran fine the first time and then got stuck the second time around.  No clue why but I'll get it eventually.